# Gitlab assign commit to other user

Tags: gitlab

I made a commit on a computer account with multple users. 
Both

```
git config --global user.email
git config --global user.name
```

were set wrong. Now the commits are listed under the wrong name.

So, is there a way to assign a pushed commit on gitlab to another user?

Answer (score 3):

From as I know you can do revert from the Commit details page, but it depends on the GitLab version. 
 The committer is the current authenticated user on that computer, so you may have to do the git config settings again after the revert. You can have a look here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html , it may help.

Just found that you also can undo the las commit with:

> git revert HEAD

Very useful : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/university/training/topics/rollback_commits.html